# Apache and PHP multi-request handle

Tags: php, node.js, multithreading, apache

As far as I know, if a request is sent from an IP to an Apache+PHP webserver, then all further requests are blocked until the first request is resolved.

I have developed an application on a nodeJS server and that application communicates with another server using HTTP requests, when certain events are triggered by user clients. The 2nd server uses Apache+PHP.

The communication path would be: 
User---socket.io--->  nodeJS  ---HTTP request--->  Apache+PHP

The problem comes when 1000 users do something and 1000 requests are sent in a second from the nodeJS server to the Apache+PHP server. This causes huge delays, because the requests are handled 1 by 1, because the Apache+PHP server considers that they come from the same IP/client (the nodeJS server), even though the requests actually come from 1000 different clients before hitting the nodeJS server.

I am in need of some suggestions on how to handle this.

Comment: How do you get an impression that "if a request is sent from an IP to an Apache+PHP webserver, then all further requests are blocked until the first request is resolved"? Although I am not an expert on Apache and PHP, it will be a failure for the designer if it really works that way.

Comment: You could put a reverse proxy in front of apache which round robins to the same or multiple upstreams.

Comment: @Jacob if I do a test from my PC and I open multiple PHP pages of the Apache+PHP webserver, then the all requests are blocked (they show loading bar in the browser developer tools) until the first request is resolved

Comment: @NVG this is what you observed, which could have many reasons. Each connection uses different client port and to server it's different connection. I suspect it's your application has some kind of locks caused this issue, such as database, session, ...

Comment: @Jacob so you think that it's the browser actually who holds the 2nd,3rd,4th request from being passed over to the server, until the first request is resolved?

Comment: @NVG No, I suspect it's your server code or configuration. Browser can support multiple connections (with a small limit)